# Oracle Database On Multiple Tablespaces

Tags: database, oracle, oracle11g, tablespace

Our Oracle database vendor suggested to create multiple tablespaces (ex: TS1, TS2 ... etc) on different disk drives to boost performance of read/write, however, I just figured out that one tablespace is full of data while others almost empty, did the vendor miss any extra configuration? if the vendor point of view is applicable then does this mean Oracle will manage distributing the data automatically on tablespaces and is it going to be equally or randomly?

Comment: In earlier days when a table space was often hosted by one physical disc it was more important to make a proper table space design, e.g. store data in different table space than the indexes in order to gain some speed. Nowadays with SAN and/or virtual infrastructure this is not so important anymore. Do not expect any performance *boost* by this.

Answer (score 0):

Well, your database already uses different tablespaces (see an example below, list from `dba_tablespaces`). I presume you meant to create ones you'd explicitly use.

The most obvious performance benefit would be to separate data and index tablespaces and put them to separate disks. Indexes often consume much space, as much as data (or even more). If you choose to do so, don't forget to specify which tablespace to use while storing data or indexes. For example, in my 11gXE:

```
SQL> show user
USER is "SYS"
SQL> select tablespace_name from dba_tablespaces;

TABLESPACE_NAME
------------------------------
SYSTEM
SYSAUX
UNDOTBS1
TEMP
USERS

SQL> connect scott/tiger
Connected.
SQL> create table testt (id number) tablespace users;

Table created.

SQL> create index i1t on testt (id) tablespace system;

Index created.

SQL>
```

(The last one doesn't make much sense; don't create anything in `SYSTEM` tablespace yourself, but I didn't feel like creating a new tablespace).

Comment: So that old chestnut about separating tables and indexes for performance still has followers?  It is not true, nor was it ever really true.  Accessing a table by index is a serial operation - the index 'read' must be completed before it can even be known where to go for the referenced data.  There simply cannot be any conflict or contention between them.  Even if all are on a single physical disk.

Comment: Aha; thank you, @EdStevens. I'm not a DBA so I certainly won't argue, I don't have required knowledge. I understand what you are saying. It make sense if it is me who reads some data from a table - OK, index is read first, data next. But, what if there are 500 users who - more or less at the same time - read and write data on the same disk? Wouldn't separating tablespaces / data files on different disks help, even a little bit?

Comment: 500 concurrent users? So what?  Think about what this supposed performance gain is based on:  contention at the read-write head on an individual spindle.  And that is necessarily serialized to one single read or write request at a time. The contention is going to be between concurrent users regardless of if an individual user needs an index or the table itself. Now consider that on modern storage systems a 'disk' is quite likely an abstraction of multiple spindles, throw in disk buffering ....  (to be continued)

Comment: and that multiple 'disks' at the OS level may actually map back to the same set of physical disks ...  Now, there is an argument to be made in favor of putting indexes and tables in separate tablespaces.  But that is in favor of ease of management, not performance.

Comment: I see. Thanks again, @EdStevens. Therefore, my "answer" is less than useful so I'd delete it, but - your comments are valuable so I'll leave it (unless you post your own answer; let me know and I'll remove what I wrote). Sadly, it seems that the OP's database vendor is wrong as well.

Comment: "it seems that the OP's database vendor is wrong as well. "  Unfortunately, that's not terribly unusual.

Answer (score 0):

@user2155873 You said,

> "if the vendor point of view is applicable then does this mean Oracle
>   will manage distributing the data automatically on tablespaces and is
>   it going to be equally or randomly?"

Oracle will not do this for you. A table (or table partition) or index (or index partition) can only occupy one tablespace. You must tell Oracle which tablespace you want an object to be stored in. Simply creating more tablespaces won't do anything unless you actually move tables and/or indexes around between them.